# KIE Workbench maven dependency exclusion

Tags: drools, kie, kie-workbench

Is it possible to exclude dependencies from the maven project within `drools-workbench`?

Below is the error when trying to edit the pom.xml and add exclusion on a external library (which contains domain objects) added as dependency:

> Unrecognised tag: 'exclude' (position: START_TAG seen .. \n... @16:10)

Comment: Please provide more context of the file. Obviously `exclude` is invalid at this point, where did you get the idea that it should work?

Comment: Its `<exclusion>` not `<exclude>`